# Can Eclipse bundle project refer to Apache felix deployed within web application for import package?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I am really new to OSGi. I am able to run struts2 OSGi sample project, which starts up Apache felix from the web application. I am using Jetty to deploy the web application from eclipse, which I believe is a separate jvm process.

Now I am trying to create a bundle project which should import packages from the deployed "struts2 OSGi sample project" application. But I don't know how to setup eclipse to point to the deployed felix bundles.

My project looks like this http://classreloadingwebapp.blogspot.sg/2012/04/class-reloading-4-using-struts2-osgi.html

But I have no idea how to start creating bundles now as I am not able to import package.